Converting a NO solid state relay to NC
AQV258 is a SSR RELAY SPST-NO 20MA 0-1500V

I know that it can be configured to be a NC relay instead of a NO relay, but I have been unable to find a diagram on how to do this.
Any geniuses out there got an answer❓
https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/search_num/index.jsp?c=detail&part_no=AQV258


have you looked where the URL ends up?

No, this cannot be changed.

How are you driving the LED? If you are using a push-pull output, simply by moving the from K to A and changing the other pin to the opposite voltage (for example, Vcc to GND), you end up with NC. Add a complete schematic so we can help.

Thank you for answering Sadart! The diagram is of the part itself, and you mention using  "K to A" but the drawing only has numbers 1-6 ? ?
What I am wanting to do is have the "relay" closed, so power to a circuit is provided.  But when I add an exterior voltage source to the circuit, I want to disconnect the internal source from the circuit.

CONTINUED: The chip is constructed to work the other way, but I understand there is some way, using external components or perhaps what you are suggesting above to hold the "relay" closed until the LED is activated, and when that happens, the "relay" will open, and in my case, disconnect the internal power supply.  I hope this is clearer now!

I have found an optocoupler that is Normally Closed, which is exactly what I needed, but it still would be good to know how to add external components to a NO unit to make it function as a NC unit.
